# Default Redirect after login based on destination

Tags: 8, users, redirection

I have custom routing and a user controller in a module that redirects authenticated users to a private area on a site.

It works fine when users are coming from the login page - redirects them to a dashboard at a custom user page - but I would like users to continue to the page they are requesting if they come to the site from a link.

It is common for users to share links to internal content and they are then having to log in and get to the link from their dashboard which is causing some annoyance.

I have reasonably simple routing for the user page and a controller in my module that redirects users to their `userPage`. Is their a way to have this not redirect depending on the link they are requesting?

Answer (score 2):

You mite need to add 'destination' query parameter for shared link.

For example: `https://www.drupal.org/user/login?destination=search/site/destinations`

Comment: How do I get that as a query parameter in the original redirect to `/user/login`?

Comment: @Jeff You can use `drupal_get_destination()` to get that. See more [How to add a "?destination=URL" to the request new password link | Drupal 7 guide on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/how-to-add-a-destinationurl-to-the-request-new-password)

Answer (score 2):

If the pages are giving an access denied message and you want them to login first then it sounds like you might want [r4032login](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login)

As the project page says:

> Redirect the HTTP 403 error page to the Drupal /user/login page with
>   an optional message that reads:
>
> "Access denied! You must login to view this page."
>
> Also, the desired page is appended in the url query string so that,
>   once login is successful, the user is taken directly where they were
>   originally trying to go.